# Problem with Certbot after Ubuntu upgrade to 22.04

Tags: upgrade, 22.04, snap, certificates, letsencrypt

I have a problem with Certbot after upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04. I tried to reinstall Certbot without success. Then I tried to install Certbot with snap, and I have the same problem:

```
 certbot --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/certbot", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('certbot', 'console_scripts', 'certbot')())
  File "/usr/local/bin/certbot", line 22, in importlib_load_entry_point
    for entry_point in distribution(dist_name).entry_points
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 957, in distribution
    return Distribution.from_name(distribution_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 548, in from_name
    raise PackageNotFoundError(name)
importlib.metadata.PackageNotFoundError: No package metadata was found for certbot
```

I cant renew certs for my domains. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within the error message provided in the question, I noticed the problematic Certbot's executable is `/usr/local/bin/certbot`.

Usually the executable files located in `/usr/local/bin` are a kind of *custom* installations and they take precedence over these installed by the package managers, because of the default structure of the `$PATH` variable - to check it run:

```bash
echo $PATH
```

On the other hand, packages installed with `apt` could be found in the other directories like `/usr/bin` or `/usr/sbin`, or `/bin`, or `/snap/bin` for the `snap` packages, etc.

So different versions of a command (with the same name) could exist in different directories which belong to your `$PATH`. To find which one takes precedence over the others you can use the command:

```bash
which certbot
```

To find the locations of all executable files named `certbot` within the directories in the `$PATH` use the command:

```bash
which -a certbot
```

In a case the above command outputs more than one line - for example:

```bash
/usr/local/bin/certbot
/usr/bin/certbot
/bin/certbot
```

You can try to renew your certificates by the second (or the third) command by calling it with its full path - i.e. `/usr/bin/certbot`.

If this works,you can safely remove the obsolete executable `/usr/local/bin/certbot` which probably was installed a long time ago while you've followed some guide which you can't remember right now :)

Comment: Thanks, I learned something from this. I checked in my server and `certbot` is indeed in /usr/bin, so that matches.

Comment: Big Thanks! It works, you safe me :)

Comment: I'm happy to help! :)